# iBeacons - locationManager:didEnterRegion callback and UUID

Tags: ibeacon, ios7.1

Lets say I have four beacons configured with same UUID , same major value and different minor values.Then I am monitoring the regions using only the UUID and imagine the a scenario where the four beacons overlaps with each other, assume when entering the store. Will I get four locationManager:didEnterRegion callbacks for each beacon or will it be only one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only get one.  (Small caveat:  iOS sometimes sends multiple callbacks, but this is rare, and can be considered a glitch in CoreLocation.  These glitches have nothing to do with multiple beacons in a region being detected.)

Also note that you won't know which of the iBeacons is visible when you get the entry notification.  To get the specific identifier, you will need to start ranging.

Comment: Thanks david one more scenario , lets three beacons overlaps and while user is moving the fourth one also becomes visible , what would happen on scenario like that ? Will "didEnterRegion" be called again ? , I guess it's not.

Comment: No, you will only et didEnterRegion again after all beacons in the region have disappeared then at least one has reappeared.